# How can I specify which device to open in a driver that supports 2 different devices?

Tags: c, linux, driver

I have a driver that supports multiple devices that aren't identical but are similar. I'm doing this so that the same library APIs can be used when writing apps for the devices.

Is there a way to specify which particular device to use in an app?

Is it possible to make an ioctl call before an open call in order to set which particular device gets used the next time open is called?

Comment: This seems backwards.  The app shouldn't have to care that certain devices happen to be similar - that's the driver's job.  The driver should figure out what device it is dealing with and provide proper abstraction.  If there is no way to probe the device for this information, it can be resolved with a load-time argument.  If a machine can have more than one of these devices attached, each device should have its own device node, and the app just opens one of them.

Comment: Well I want to be able to have both devices on the same machine and allow the user space app to select which device to use. One instance where the user space app would need to know which device it is using is in a memory test program. One device only has 1 memory area to test and the other device has 3.

Comment: Hmm, I reread your comment. If each device has its own device node would this translate to multiple entries in /dev/, one for each device?

Comment: Yes.  For example, if a machine has multiple disks, there are entries /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, and so on.  A userspace app does not have to know that two of these are actually flash drives and share the same driver.

Comment: So if I were to do this for each unique device/vendor id only and just save each device for that particular device/vendor id in an array would there be any issues assuming that it doesn't matter which specific device gets used among identical devices only that I can differentiate between different devices.

Comment: I don't quire understand.  I'd still stick to the "one file per device" abstraction just to keep things simple.  Then you'd have some way of returning device information to the application.  For example: the app opens the device file, does an ioctl to find out what the test areas are, and proceeds by mmapping areas of the file that correspond to the test areas.  I'm not saying this is the only way to do it, by the way - just my thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to deal with this issue is to have a separate device node in `/dev/` for each device and have your driver provide an `ioctl()` that would return identification information for the corresponding device such as vendor, model and serial number. That would allow a userspace application to tell different devices apart. Depending on your exact needs, a few accompanying entries in `sysfs` (`/sys`) might also make sense.

You might want to have a look at some common existing APIs for ideas. For example, the [V4L2](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/v4l2spec.html) API contains the [VIDIOC_QUERYCAP ioctl()](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/vidioc-querycap.html) that provides enough information for an application to be able to tell discrete devices apart.

Comment: This seems like it would only let the user space app know which device it has opened but wouldn't let the user space app control which device it actually opens. If I open device 1 then close it and open device 2, I end up with the same device both times. At least this seems to be the case for identical devices I have yet to put the two different devices on the same machine.

Comment: Looks like it's the same for different devices. Opening any one of the different device nodes doesn't make a difference since it only matters on what the open function actually does. Since the open function won't have any way to know which device the user space app actually wants, using separate device nodes doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @user1061166: The `open()` implementation in your driver should be able to tell which device it should use by examining *which* device node was opened. The application differentiates the devices by their device node - it does *not* select a device *after* opening the device node.

Comment: But how does the driver know which device node was opened?

Comment: @user1061166: The `open()` implementation takes a couple of arguments. One of them (`struct file *filp` IIRC) contains enough information to find out the device minor number and - I think - its name. Have a look at LDD 3 or another Linux kernel programming book.